# Is this condition enogh to guarantee that this vector is parallel?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

> Let $D\subseteq TM$ a totally geodesic distribution of $M\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n+p}$ (with the induced metric), and $\xi$ unit and normal to $M$, such that $R^\perp(X,Y)\xi=0$ for $X,Y\in D$, is this enough information to guarantee that $\xi$ is $D$-parallel? In other words, this implies that $\nabla^\perp_X \xi=0$ for all $X\in D$?

My idea is to fix a point and use the parallel transport on curves such that their velocity are in $D$, to define a normal vector field wich dosent depends on the path by the curvature condition (for simplicity lets assume simply connected), but im not able to prove that this new vector coincides with $\xi$

Any suggestion? it this even true? Thanks for any future help!

Comment: $\nabla^\perp$ and $R^\perp$ are the natural connection and curvature on the normal bundle?

Comment: yes, they are. I think that maybe i even have the extra hypothesis that the integral submanifolds of D are opens sets of affins subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^{n+p}$, but i didnt thought that this was relevant

Comment: I was going to ask if $D$ was integrable, but then I assumed you meant it need not be. I haven't thought through the calculation yet.

Comment: with totally geodesic i mean that $\nabla_T S\in D$ for $T,S\in D$, wich implies that the distribution is integrable since $[T,S]=\nabla_T S-\nabla_S T\in D$